# How to show a jQuery page inside a popover?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, popover

I'm using jQuery Mobile to develop an iPad app.
I want to have a toolbar with a button that displays a popover when clicked.
After some search I found this [jQuery popover implementation](https://github.com/harryhorn/jquery-popover). It works fine but without any styling for the header or content.
I then made some tweaks and decided to set only a content which would be a regular jQuery page like this:

```
<div id="popover-add-project" data-role="page" data-url="popover-add-project">
  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>Add New Project</h1>
  </div><!-- /header -->      
  <div data-role="content">
    <p>project form to be inserted here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that it displays an empty popover.
A simplified code is [here](http://ecil.teodo.ro/files/www.zip) and can be executed by opening index.html on a webkit browser (I tested only on Safari and Chrome) and clicking Add button.

jquery.popover.js contains popover related code.

app.js creates the popover for the Add button.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I want to have a behavior similar to a jQuery dialog, but with a popover.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just need content inside a popover, you should use the upcoming popup widget as @Phill Pafford mentions.

If you want full pages inside a popover you can try [multiview](https://github.com/frequent/multiview), which I'm almost done developing.

Here is one of my [test pages](http://www.stokkers.mobi/jqm/multiview/test/fix_triplePop.html) which also has a popover (top right).

[image]

Popovers are panels, which use the [JQM pageContainer](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html) changePage option to enable panel navigation and integration into the JQM and browser history.

I have not done a popover only version of the plugin so currently you would have to set up your page like this:

```
<div data-role="page" id="YOUR_ID" data-wrapper="true"> 

    <div data-role="panel" data-id="my_main_panel_id" data-panel="main">

         <div data-role="page" id="page_A1" data-show="first">

            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
               <h1>Local Header</h1>
               <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="iconposSwitcher-div">
                    <a href="#" data-transition="pop" data-role="button" data-panel="pop_one" data-icon="info" data-iconpos="left" class="toggle_popover">pop1</a>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content"></div>
         </div>
      </div>

      <div data-role="panel" data-id="pop_one" data-panel="popover" data-triangle="top" class="popover1">
           <div data-role="page" id="page_D1" data-show="first">
               <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a">
                   <h1>Pop</h1>
               </div> 
               <div data-role="content"></div>
            </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="page_D2">
                <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a">
                   <h1>Pop internal page</h1>
                </div>
                <div data-role="content"></div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

So to use popovers, you will need to

- add **data-wrapper="true"** to your page to init the plugin
- use a fullwidth main background panel
- panels need a role = **data-role="panel"**, a type **data-panel="main|mid|menu|popover"** and a data-id  **data-id="your_panel_name"**
- one page on each panel needs **data-show="first"**, without it your panels will be blank
- you can add as many popover panels as you want inside your wrapper page
- you can add as many nested pages inside your popovers as you want
- nested pages don't need to be "on board" when you load the page. You can pull them in like JQM through links or changePage calls.
- to pull a page in or link to and from a page inside a panel, changePage like this:

  ```
  $.mobile.changePage('#pop_two', {transition: 'slide', pageContainer: $('div:jqmData(id="your_panel_name")') });
  ```
- or using links with **data-panel** specified:

  ```
  <a href="#pop_two" data-panel="your_panel_name">Button</a>
  ```
- there is no need to include all popover pages at first page load. You can pull them in like regular JQM and they will be removed again once the user leaves or the popover closes.
- to toggle a popover you need a toggle button with class of **toggle_popover** and **data-panel="your_panel_name"** to tell the plugin which popover to open.
- on smartphones your popovers will be fullscreen pages

The plugin still has some bugs and requires a custom JQM version with 4 small tweaks (most important adding pageContainer to the JQM history), but other than that it's working ok.

Comment: iOS popovers have an arrow pointing to the widget that opened it. I have seen some apps that were rejected by Apple because there were no arrows pointing back to the button. Is there a chance to have the above mentioned popups with an arrow? Thanks a lot for your detailed reply.

Comment: yup, set data-triangle="top|bottom" on the popover and in the plugin css, set overflow-y: visible on popovers. Works in the demo page when you override overflow-x:hidden in Firebug. I currently disabled triangles, because I need to find a way to prevent pages "leaking" out of the popover during transitions. Eventually they should be there though (maybe also left|right but these are tricky to position)

Answer (score 5):

`data-role="page"` attribute sets css property `display` to `none`. so add `display: block` inside style attribute of `#popover-add-project`.

`<div style="display: block" id="popover-add-project" data-role="page" data-url="popover-add-project">`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It really makes the content appear in the popover, but not formatted, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5):

You could start to play with the next jQM iteration ( 1.2 ) popup functionality

- http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/popup/index.html

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to take a look at that.