# how to extract a value of a name-value pair from a list/array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to extract an id from an object.

The object `data.prevPage[0].attributes` returns this:

```
[  data-show="first"
 , id="brandlist"
 , data-role="page"
 , data-url="brandlist"
 , data-dom-cache="true"
 , class="ui-page-active ui-page ui-body-c"
 , tabindex="0"
 , style="min-height: 927px; margin-left: 250px; width: 671px;"
 ]
```

If I console `console.log( data.prevPage[0].attributes.id )` I'm getting

```
id="brandlist"
```

**Question:**
How do I get `brandlist` only? Something like `data.prevPage[0].attributes[id]` doesn't work.

Thanks

**EDIT:**
So, going with the answer given:

```
  var test = data.prevPage[0].attributes.id,
      el   = $('#'+test)
```

produces the following error:

```
   Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object Attr]
```

which tells me, the console does return id="brandlist" and not brandlist....

Comment: Can you re-phrase that? Don't you already have that which you request in the console.log line? If console.log prints the value when you try to acces it one way, why not access it again later in the same way?

Comment: yeah. I want the `value only`, not the `name/value` pair. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yup, that's better. I see from the other text that you got bitten in the behind by console.log's formatting. Happens to the best of us. Fwiw - it aparently defers the output of some objects in some instances (I forget which and when). The point being you could get identical outputs from a variable that had changed between the two calls. Ah, console.log - she's a tricky beast indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you allready did use the correct answer when you typed it in the console. It is:

```
data.prevPage[0].attributes.id
```

Comment: but it returns `id="brandslist"` and I only need `brandlist`. Isn*t there a way to get the value only?

Comment: no, it will return `brandslist`. The prefix "id=" and the surrounding quote-marks come from the console.log-function

Comment: This question is coming from the same person who's given [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10862588/400127)? This is... strange... to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

Allright, the question was stupid...

This works:

```
 data.prevPage.attr('id')
```

which returns

```
 brandlist
```

(of course it does...)