# jQuery Mobile like navigation menu inside a side Panel for desktop app?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm looking for a solution that will help me do the following... I would like to develop a (namely desktop usage) website that has a slide out Panel in it

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/panels/#

but within that Panel, I would like the navigation for the site to act like it's own jQuery app, with nested menus and back and home buttons.  The jQuery framework for creating this type of navigation is all based on multi-page documents (using  tags for declaring the content of "page") and pages are on the same level as a side out panel.  It doesn't seem like there is an easy way to stick "pages" inside a panel.  Also, nested lists are being deprecated in the newest jQuery, so I would like to stay away from them as well (not sure they ever supported back button anyway).

Can anyone suggest a strategy for making this happen?  I have thought about trying to put the navigation inside an iframe within the Panel, but then the menu couldn't communicate outside of the iframe to the rest of the app.  I've also run across this

http://simplesplitview.sourceforge.net/

which seems to kind of do what I want if I could put the mini menu inside a Panel, but not sure how solid the code is and would be more interested in a pure jQuery Mobile (or other good framework) solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is not so easy. I have spent quite some time on it getting a plugin to work, but have not updated it from JQM 1.2, because 1.5 should start to support this in one way or another. If you want to give multiview a try:

[SO answer how to setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856529/how-to-show-a-jquery-page-inside-a-popover/10862588#10862588) | 
[Github repo](https://github.com/frequent/multiview) |
[sample page](http://www.stokkers.mobi/jqm/multiview/test/fix_triplePop.html)

Comment: Why haven't you yanked the slider code out of JQM into a self-contained plugin? That's what I'd do. ;)

Answer (score 0):

So, I've come up with a pretty reasonable solution (for my needs) that allows me to use the latest version of jQuery Mobile and all the bells and whistles it contains.

Using this plug-in

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/

I am able to put the entire slide out side menu in it's own iframe, and navigate using data-role="pages", sub-menus, back buttons, etc, just as if you were on a mobile phone.  If I need to communicate any thing to the other window, I use said plug-in above with various command messages ("logout", "refresh", etc) that I identify in the $.receiveMessage function.  I am hoping to get the chance to write up the process in a more instructive tutorial form when I get some time, but if there are any questions, feel free to respond to this answer.